# Jquery preventDefault() on Android zoom snippet

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, zooming, preventdefault

I have some event binded to a link, for example:

```
<a class='mylink' href='01'>My Link</a>

$(document).on('touchstart', '.mylink', function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   $(document).find('#someblock').fadeIn();

})
```

Sure, it does work ok. But on Android Chrome if you have some links close one to each other, after tapping on some of this links, a zoom snippet is appearing (to let user select a link he wants and not to misstap). And if I tap my link with preventDefault() from this snippet, preventDefault() does not work and browser attempts to load an URL from "href" attribute.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try to use "click" event instead of touch start:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mylink', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(document).find('#someblock').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: try below:
$(document).on('click', '.mylink', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(document).find('#someblock').fadeIn();
})